# android device not getting detected by adb in virtual machine

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I created a guest vm on my Ubuntu desktop using KVM.I have installed android sdk in the guest vm.I have forwarded usb from host to guest machine using this script:

[image]

Now when I try to get all the android devices attached to guest machine using "adb devices" I don't get any list of devices.Output shown is as follows:

[image]

But when I check usb details using "lsusb" then I get all the devices attached to guest machine which ensures that usb port has been successfully forwarded from host to guest machine.You can see the output of "lsusb" here:

[image]

As you can see from the output that my motorola device is being detected here in the guest machine but not getting detected by adb.I have made some changes in 51-android.rules (/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules) file so as to automatically allow debugging on my android device.Those changes are as follows:

[image]

Can anyone please help me to figure out why adb is not detecting my android device?

Comment: enable media-device(MTP)...this worked in my case...

Comment: hey.. i have already enabled that

Comment: Post your code and diagnostics as text, not screen shots please.

Answer (score 0):

as in the script:

```
<address bus='3' ...>
```

in the lsusb output:

```
Bus 001
```

fix and retry ;)

Comment: hey..address bus='3' is taken from "lsusb" output on host.Bus id and device id which is given in the script is that of host as it forwards that usb to guest machine whereas Bus 001 is the bus id of that usb in guest machine.